# Pass various data from Child to Parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, child-to-parent, custom-event

Hello everybody I have a child LWC inside of a Parent LWC. In the child component I have some input fields that I pass to the parent component. In one of them I have a combobox field so when the user picks one or other, two boolean variables are studied. So what I need to do is to pass the combobox selected value and the two boolean variables.
My child component .js looks like this:

```
ocultarCampoRazonSocial=false;
ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido=false;
tipoPersona;
handleTipoPersona(event){
    this.tipoPersona = event.target.value;
    if(this.tipoPersonaValue === 'F'){
        this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = false;
        this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = true;
    }else{
        if(this.tipoPersonaValue === 'J'){
            this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = true;
            this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = false;
        }
    }
    //Create Event
    const tipoPersonaEvent = new CustomEvent('gettipopersonavalue',{
        detail: this.tipoPersona
    });
    //Dispatch Event
    this.dispatchEvent(tipoPersonaEvent);
}
```

The problem is when I create the CustomEvent. I only pass the user's selected value but I do not know how to pass the ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido and ocultarCampoRazonSocial variables.

And also I would like to know how would I have to work in the parent component in order to obtain each one or the three values I get from the child component.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: instead of just passing single variable, you can pass the JSON object containing all the properties that you'd like to pass to parent

Answer (score 0):

You need pass them in an object.

```
const tipoPersonaEvent = new CustomEvent('gettipopersonavalue',{
        detail: {
               'tipoPersona':this.tipoPersona,
               'ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido':this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido ,
               'ocultarCampoRazonSocial':this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial ,
                }
    });
    //Dispatch Event
    this.dispatchEvent(tipoPersonaEvent);
```

```
//you can pass multiple values using an Object and get values like - 

event.detail.tipoPersona;
event.detail.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido ;
event.detail.ocultarCampoRazonSocial;

console.log(event.detail);// this will show you the entire obejct.
```